# JQUERY, Extract only the first paragraph

Tags: jquery, string, ckeditor

Given a block of text in a TEXT EDITOR (CKEDITOR), with paragraphs contained in PARAGRAPH tags, how can I do in JQUERY to extract only the first paragraph

Example:

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah 123123blah blah

blah blah blah blah b1212lah

blah blah blah blaasdasdadsh blah

To Just:

blah blah blah blah blah

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying the suggestions as follows but it errors: 
newTitle = $(newTitle).$("p:first").text();
original code: 
newTitle = $(newTitle).text();

Comment: What is newTitle meant to be?

Try `newTitle = $("#cke_contents_editor1 iframe").contents().find('p:first').text();`

Comment: newTitle is the variable I'm using to store the TEXT EDITOR contents via CKEDITOR:
var newTitle = CKEDITOR.instances.meeting_notes.getData();

Comment: I tried splitting out the various functions but that didn't seem to do the trick? Is this because of CKEDITOR somehow?

Comment: I see now, `$(newTitle).find("p:first").text();` should work.

Comment: @Brian, I tried that it seems to be breaking.. Here is the full line of code: Any ideas? thxs
newTitle = $(newTitle).find("p:first").text();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the :first selector:

```
$('p:first');
```

Comment: make sure you include the specific `div` as well, otherwise you'll only get the very first `p` on the page

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, please see comment above. thxs

Answer (score 2):

Since CKeditor is in an iframe, you might need something along the lines of:

```
$("#cke_contents_editor1 iframe").contents().find('p:first').text()
```

to extract the text.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: 
newTitle = $(newTitle).contents().find('p:first').text();

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if CKEditor would affect this in any way, but with jQuery you should be able to use:

```
$("p:first").text();
```

To get the text in the first `<p>` element. If the paragraphs are wrapped by a `<div>` or another element with a specific ID, you can do:

```
$("#id-of-div p:first").text();
```

Comment: Since the content is in CKEDITOR (iframed) I have the content in a variable not a DIV, how can I use a variable in your second example? thxs

Comment: Try the following: `$(newTitle).find("p:first").text();`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work... Full line: 

var newTitle = CKEDITOR.instances.meeting_notes.getData();
newTitle = $(newTitle).find("p:first").text();

Comment: What exactly is the output of newTitle? Can you update your original post with the full contents of that variable?